# Python - How to use finditer regex?

Tags: html, regex, python-2.7

I would like to find every instance of img src="([^"]+)" that is preceded by the div class="grid" and succeeded by div class="orderplacebut" in some HTML code i.e. I want to find all the images in the div container called "grid".

If I used findall it will only return one image because div class="grid" appears just once on the webpage and therefore it will only return one of the following image URLs (makes sense). So I would like to iterate the findall regex so that it runs again, and returns the second instance of the image URL, and then the third and so forth. Is this possible using finditer, and how would I use it in the code?

The code below is my findall regex that only returns the one URL.

```
from urllib import urlopen
from re import findall
import re

dennisov_url = 'https://denissov.ru/en/'
dennisov_html = urlopen(dennisov_url).read()

# Print all images between div class="grid" and div class="orderplacebut"
# Because the regex spans over several lines, use DOTALL flag to include
# every character between, including new lines

watch_image_urls = findall('<div class="grid".*<img src="([^"]+)".*<div class="orderplacebut"', dennisov_html, flags=re.DOTALL) 
print watch_image_urls
```

Answer (score 0):

Really, use another approach with a parser (not tested due to `.ru` domain which is blocked here):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

dennisov_url = 'https://denissov.ru/en/'
dennisov_html = requests.get(dennisov_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(dennisov_html.text, 'lxml')

images = soup.select('div.grid > img')
```